# Can ParallelDo speed up a counting problem?

Tags: parallelization

How to make parallelize the following code keeping the same "idea". The example I have in mind is more complicated, but I would like to know if a program of this structure can be parallelized?

```
c = 0
ParallelDo[If[RandomReal[] > 0.5, c += 1], {i, 100}]
```

Comment: Well, not with exactly this structure, AFAICT. But you could generate lists of random numbers in parallel, count the applicable elements of these lists in parallel, and then add these counts together to get the amount that should be added to `c`. Depending on what side-effects we assume for the individial operations, this may or may not be a valid approach for your real program--it's rather hard to tell from your example. What I can tell you is that this parallelization will almost certainly require changing more of your program than a simple substition of `ParallelDo` for `Do`.

Comment: For parallelization, the first thing to do is to try to formulate the problem in terms of functions with no side effects.  That rules out using `=` on any global variable.  So think about whether you can use `ParallelTable` instead (what Oleksandr said).  Before trying to parallelize, also consider vectorization, i.e. doing arithmetic on arrays of numbers in one go.  Many array operations are internally parallelized already.

Comment: This might be too far from what you want, but maybe `evs = Table[ParallelSubmit[Boole[RandomReal[] > 0.5]], {10000}];` and then `Total@WaitAll[evs]`

Comment: @OleksandrR. "count the applicable elements of these lists in parallel". How would you do that? Could you write an example code?

Comment: @lagoa I think you need to give more details about your program structure before we can usefully comment further. For instance, what if you are using `RandomReal` as a stand-in for some function whose result depends on previously accumulated state? What if `AddTo` on `c` is just your way of representing an operation with complicated side effects for the purposes of the example? Since you talk about the idea and the structure and not the specific code, I worry that anything relating to your example will turn out not to be what you actually want.

Comment: `ParallelCombine` and `ParallelSubmit` are probably the most general parallelization constructs and I think therefore the most useful for parallelizing an arbitrary program. But at the moment I can't even tell whether your program is even conceptually parallelizable since the example needs to be restructured significantly before gaining performance (see @Pillsy's excellent answer) and we have no way of telling whether this restructuring would have any sensible analog in your actual program.

Answer (score 6):

So, in the first place, if you're concerned about performance, you probably don't want to be looping like that and incrementing a counter. It's not going to be as fast as you'd like it to be. Unparallelized, this...

```
AbsoluteTiming[c = 0; 
 Do[If[RandomReal[] > 0.5, c += 1], {i, 100000}];
 c]

(* {0.111647, 49853} *)
```

...is about half as fast as this:

```
Count[RandomReal[{}, 100000], x_ /; x > 0.5] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.053361, 49891} *)
```

Just generating all the numbers at once with a single call to `RandomReal` helps a lot, and it's likely that using [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Count.html) helps some as well. We can speed it up more with [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitStep.html) (it's a little convoluted because the test is `Greater`, not `GreaterEqual`, which meshes better with `UnitStep`, but that has minimal effect on the time):

```
100000 - Total[UnitStep[0.5 - RandomReal[{}, 100000]]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.002914, 49736} *)
```

OK, maybe you want more than 10^5 numbers. Maybe you want 100 million, and you're worried that one kernel isn't enough to keep things moving along:

```
100000000 - Total[UnitStep[0.5 - RandomReal[{}, 100000000]]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {3.494106, 50000451} *)
```

That's taking three seconds. You can **notice** that! Now maybe it's time to think about parallelization. First, we want to start up all our kernels in order to make our timings fair.

```
LaunchKernels[];
```

That takes a couple seconds on my computer. Now, I can throw all 8 of my kernels at the problem!

```
Total[
  ParallelTable[
   10000000 - Total[UnitStep[0.5 - RandomReal[{}, 10000000]]],
   {10}]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.993367, 49996624} *)
```

It's about 3.5 times as fast; when you consider that I only have 4 cores and the "extra" 4 kernels are there due to [hyper-threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), this is quite respectable.

Note that in order to keep things as simple as possible, I didn't use any side-effects on variables, I didn't rely on any fancy local definitions (including function definitions), and I tried to use built-in Mathematica functions for everything. The four-fold speedup from parallelization is nothing to sneeze at, but I got a **forty**-fold speedup by choosing the right functions to accomplish the task.